# How can I play multiple videos after first video is end in jwplayer?

Tags: jquery, video, jwplayer, jwplayer6

Oncomplete of the video only first video is playing but unable to play the second video. How can I play the second video?

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer('myPlayer');
  playerInstance.setup({ 
    playlist: [
    {
      file: myvideo.mp4
    }
    ],
   autostart: true,
   icons: false,
    height: 340,
    width: 680,                 
    wmode: "transparent",
    skin: 'roundster'
  });
playerInstance.onComplete(function() {
    jwplayer().load([               
    {                                   
    file: "myvideo1.mp4",
    file: "myvideo2.mp4"
    }                   
    ]);
    jwplayer().play();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me when I loaded only one video in the onComplete function. In order to load and play multiple videos, you need to create a playlist.

https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference#playlist